# False positives in Location monitoring with Android

Tags: android, machine-learning, location, false-positive

I have an issue with my Android app at the moment relating to false positives with location tracking using a network provider.

Essentially, 99% of the time, using this provider is more than adequate and gives me, in centre of a large town, accuracy down to 20m. However, I do get sporadic values of 300m+, which generates false-positives.

Does anyone have a pattern I could consider that'd help me test for potential spurious values and filter them out? Or a way to better handle the false results? I figured on some naive bayes probability analysis as a method for filtering results, but I'd like something much simpler if possible.

Edit: Ok, the spurious values seem to come from 3g, when WiFi doesn't appear to Work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get accuracy from location object http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()

Comment: Thanks! Forgot this was there.